# Layout for ListView at top and Buttons in Bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to display the layout with a `ListView` at top and mutliple `Buttons` at the bottom (as in pic)

[image]

Below is the code that I tried (Problem is the buttons are overlapping the list which is somewhat visible behind the buttons & the 3 buttons are not equal is size though I used the weight sum):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSelAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Select All" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I did is basically do a 2 linear layouts, 1 for the list and 1 for the button. Also setting the weight = 1 and the width = 0 will make them equal size
This code worked for me:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"  
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footerlayout"
    android:id="@+id/listviewlayout">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"               
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"               
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView> 
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footerlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDone" 
            android:text="Done" 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>   
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel" 
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"   
            >
        </Button>   
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSelAll" 
            android:text="Select All"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        </Button>   
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks that worked...one off question..I want to make a checked list which have functionality: When user clicks on checkbox it toggles and when it selects on text part a seperate functionalty gets triggered. So would you suggest the layout above or one `CheckedTextView`.

Comment: For a checked list I would suggest creating a custom layout with your textview and checkbox. I'll try to get you some sample code when I get home tonight

Answer (score 0):

Add to `LinearLayout` id property and add this to `ListView`

```
android:layout_above="@id/linear_layout_id"
```

To make buttons equal size change in their properties this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```