# ListView in RelativeLayout fills the entire height

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a main Relative layout within which there is a ListView and another Horizontal LinearLayout which I want to place at the bottom of the screen.
When the items in the list view fills up the screen, it gets hidden under the Horizontal Linear layout.
How do I restrict the ListView to take the space only till the Horozontal Linear layout and stop the content of the list view from hiding.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

here is my Layout and a screen shot of how it looks.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_chat_window"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.raoburugula.speech_soft_ivr.ChatWindow">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvMessages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="5dp"
                />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llAction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `android:visibility="invisible"` line from the LinearLayout. and check how that works. I also one time built my layout from the bottom up to allow me to place 2 buttons at the bottom of the screen, in hindsight I probably didn't need to. I wasn't able to comment on your post so I made this an answer instead.

Also have you tried a normal button in place of the FAB(FloatingActionButton)? A FAB might have properties that make it visible and at the bottom right regardless of its parents attributes

Comment: I need the Visibility attribute as I am controlling that and this issue has nothing to do with that I believe. And also how does the FAB has an impact on this.? This is to do with the Relative layout and how to place widgets within it.

Comment: Sorry about that I misread it as the linearlayout was not showing up, this guy asked a similar question and they recommended creating a layout for both the buttons and the listview within the root layout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403212/layout-for-listview-at-top-and-buttons-in-bottom

Comment: So wrap the ListView in a RelativeLayout and make that layout align to the top of the parent and to the top of the LinearLayout containing your EditText and Button

Answer (score 0):

You made the horizontal linearlayout align the bottom of parent ,yes;

and you must make your listView above the horizontal linearlayout.